# What can I do if all usb drivers on Windows 7 are broken?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, restore, system-restore

In a hush-hush operation last night I installed a USB sniffer that seems to have deleted or deactivated the usb drivers on my Windows 7 box. Even after a restart not a single usb slot works. So obviously all my usb drivers are broken.

What can I do now? Don't have a manually created restore point. Does Windows 7 DVD System Restore help?

Or are there some tools with which I could restore drivers or important system files?

Comment: It would help if you told us what "USB sniffer" you used, seems like you should be able just to install the drivers ( again ), by using a non-usb mouse and keyboard for the time being. Of course I would just reinstall Windows at this point.

Comment: It was this one --> http://code.google.com/p/busdog/. Obviously I did not install it correctly. Btw, I do not have PS2 only USB so that wouldn't have worked.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, it was solved by the OP

"Luckily I had RDP enabled and thus could login remotely, uninstall the USB sniffer and everything was working again. – Ian"

FYI for all others, the software used was from code.google.com/p/busdog

Answer (score 0):

You can check that device manager can see them and they're installed **and** enabled?

You could use the W7 disc and perform a repair?

Comment: I can't check if device manager can see them since I can not use mouse nor keyboard, all usb slots are down.

Comment: In that case, it is advisable not to boot using your normal hard-disk, but create a recovery disk or diagnostic tool like knoppix. Did your pc/laptop come with any recovery disk?

Comment: Or perhaps you can RDP from a different machine

Comment: Can you add a ps2 mouse / keyboard?

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: Luckily I had RDP enabled and thus could login remotely, uninstall the USB sniffer and everything was working again.

Comment: What was the name of the Sniffer you used?

Comment: It was this one --> code.google.com/p/busdog.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

A USB to PS2 adapter to at least get your keyboard and mouse back online, then you can access and back track actions of the sniffer.

Here is one source:
[USB to PS2](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=1950554&CatId=469)

Enter Bios and be sure USB is enabled. I have an MSI board and USB is under ***Integrated Peripherals*** for me.

save&restart

Go into Safe Mode (F8 at your mobos splash screen but prior to windows loading)

Select safe mode with networking - this should load the minimalist of working drivers to access windows and allow you to get on the web to further trouble shoot or seek guidance.

Your keyboard and mouse should work in safe mode.

Comment: Just FYI, mouse and keyboard did not work under safe mode.

Comment: Edit to answer with source for PS2 adapter.

Comment: Yeah but I suppose that wouldn't have worked since the adapter needs USB support..

Answer (score 0):

Got same issue as OP when using USB20CV R1.4.9.4 analysis tool from usb.org. The app crashed during a device test and thus could not restore the default MS or Intel drivers. None of my 14 root ports were functional under win 7 pro.

Safe mode doesn't restore drivers.

Luckily had a PS2 mouse, booted in Safe Mode using virtual keyboard to login, checked device manager and indeed all Intel USB Chipset controllers disappeared, replaced by the custom app driver stack (EHCI HSETT I think). Uninstalled the 2 instances (my MB has 2 root hubs) and hey presto, the Intel ones reappeared with proper MS or Intel drivers.

Lesson : Always keep an 80's technology device nearby when you fiddle with stuff! ;)